# Unity shader pixel manipulation

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader

I'm studying shaders in unity and I'm trying to achieve the below image. But I can't seem to make my code produce my target output. My end goal is to divide the whole image depending on the size of my array. Any idea how to correct my code?

Target output:
[image: Target output]

Code:

```
Shader "Custom/PassArray"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent"}
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
```

```
    Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"
        uniform float4 _Test [3];

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
        };

        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
            o.uv = v.uv;
            return o;
        }

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 col;

            _Test[0] = fixed4(0,0,1,1);
            _Test[1] = fixed4(1,0,0,1);
            _Test[2] = fixed4(0,1,0,1);

            //Test1: This code block produces output1 image.
            int index = round(i.uv.x*_Test.Length);
            col = _Test[index];

            //Test2: This codeblocks outputs pure green.
            //if(i.uv.x < 1/3){
            //  col = _Test[0];
            //}
            //else if(i.uv.x < 2/3){
            //  col = _Test[1];
            //}
            //else if(i.uv.x < 3/3){
            //  col = _Test[2];
            //}

            return col;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

}

Actual output:
[image]

If I understood it correctly, it's giving me black pixels because of the max i.uv.x is 1. Thus making the index 3 (based on the computation i.uv.x/_Test.Length). But I don't have index 3 in my array though.

Comment: OK. I've managed to divide the result to 3 colors using the if/else codeblock. I just changed the numbers (1/3, 2/3, 3/3) to float (1.0/3.0, 2.0/3.0, 3.0/3.0). But I cant still figure out out how to do it with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Change round to floor. Because you're rounding, values greater than 2.5 get rounded to 3. As you probably know, an array of 3 elements has no index 3, hence the black bar.

Comment: Yes. I know it has something to do with the formula. But I'm surprised it's not giving me index out of bounds error.

Comment: Well, shaders don't throw errors the way normal code does, because GPU. Does floor solve the problem?

Comment: It's giving me wrong result when i use floor. https://screencast.com/t/dZVXDNE8h3
Here's the screenshot when using ceil. https://screencast.com/t/GagoXTH8

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. Here's the updated code for anyone who may find it useful. I changed the formula from **int index = round(i.uv.x*_Test.Length);*** to **int index = ceil(i.uv.x/1_Test.Length)-1;**

`Shader "Custom/PassArray"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent"}
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha`

```
    Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"
        uniform float4 _Test [3];

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 color : COLOR;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            float4 color : COLOR;
        };

        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
            o.uv = v.uv;
            return o;
        }

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 col;

            _Test[0] = fixed4(0,0,1,1);
            _Test[1] = fixed4(1,0,0,1);
            _Test[2] = fixed4(0,1,0,1);

            //Test1:
            int index = ceil(i.uv.x/1*_Test.Length)-1;
            col = _Test[index];

            return col;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ceil - 1 is the same as floor.

Comment: ceil is different to floor since 0.1 will give you a floor of 0 and will give 1 for ceil. Also I divided it by one since max is one then just manipulate the result with -1 to start with index 0. http://http.developer.nvidia.com/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_appendix_e.html

Comment: Oops.. Didn't notice the -1. I tried floor again and removed the -1 and got the same result. I just really messed up in the parameters which should have over 1.

Comment: The additional -1 means more shader operations, which in turn means slower framerates. You want to keep shader code as clean and precise as possible to avoid performance issues.